# Python dictionary like Json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have several lists of data which looks like this:

```
ISIN        Currency    Rates
26545555    Eur     0.12345
56554455    Eur     0.25665
75884554    Eur     0.89654
```

I want to save this data into a dictionary or json like format. 
So I am trying to store the following data:

```
id: 0, ISIN: 26545555, Currency: Eur, Rates: 0.12345
id: 1, ISIN: 56554455, Currency: Eur, Rates: 0.25665
```

The problem is I am trying to use the following dictionary:

```
dict_data = {'id': '', 'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''}
```

But when I try to append data it doesn't store all of the data.

I am getting the data from an Excel sheet using Pandas. If you think I should use something else, please let me know.

Comment: The correct solution would depend on what you want to do with the data, i.e. how you intend to access it.

Comment: Have you tried just to [call `.to_json()` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use list of dicts:

```
[
 {'id': 0, 'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''},
 {'id': 1, 'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''}
]
```

or if you want dict:

```
{
 0: {'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''},
 1: {'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''}
}
```

or(partly based on Marco's suggestion):

```
{
0: [26545555, 'Eur', 0.12345],
1: [26545555, 'Eur', 0.12345]
}
```

But personally I prefer second variant if you will need to access elements by ID.

Comment: or each key being a list rather then a single value.

Comment: @MarcoGiordano what do you mean? could you suggest edit with your idea?

Comment: added an example, i think needs to be peer reviewed, feel free to discard it if you think is not relevant. Basically is saving the grid colum wise rather then row wise

Comment: @MarcoGiordano thanks, I think the main point in the answer was to keep row structure. I

Comment: Yeah, i guess it boils down on how the ids are generated, if is just a series of ints starting at 0, might save some hashing. But again that is my own speculation since I don't know how the data would be used. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One item is a dict, and group all data in a list

```
[
    {'id': 0, 'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''},
    {'id': 1, 'ISIN': '', 'Currency': ''}
]
```